# Getting different GPS coordinates in different environments

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, gps

When I use my GPS module in u-center, I get latitude of 11.27000000 and longitude of 100.34000000. But when I read and format the nmea messages in a python script I see latitude of 100.00000000 and longitude of 100.00000000. These are for example, but the difference of approximately 1.27... degrees latitude and 0.34... degrees longitude is accurate.

Here is my code:

```
import serial

try:
    gps = serial.Serial('com5', baudrate=9600)

    while True:
        ser_bytes = gps.readline()
        decoded_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
        data = decoded_bytes.split(",")
        if data[0] == '$GNRMC':
            lat_nmea = (data[3],data[4])
            lat_degrees = float(lat_nmea[0][0:2])
            if lat_nmea[1 ] == 'S':
                lat_degrees = -lat_degrees
            lat_minutes = float(lat_nmea[0][2:])
            lat = lat_degrees + (lat_minutes/60)
            lon_nmea = (data[5],data[6])
            lon_degrees = float(lon_nmea[0][0:3])
            if lon_nmea[1] == 'W':
                lon_degrees = -lon_degrees
            lon_minutes = float(lon_nmea[0][3:])
            lon = lon_degrees + (lon_minutes/60)
            print("%0.8f" %lat, "%0.8f" %lon)
        

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Keyboard Interrupt")
```

output:

> 10.0000000 100.0000000

When I just use:

```
print(data)
```

on line 11, I get the correct coordinates in the form of the GNRMC NMEA message I singled out on line 10:

> ['$GNRMC', '...', '...', '1127.00000', 'N', '10034.00000', 'W', ...]

but they're not in the format one usually expects (e.g. 11.2712345, 100.3412345). So, I use the code above to change the way they look. I can't see what I'm doing that would cause the latitude and longitude to change.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: could you include some relevant NMEA messages?   i.e. edit the question to remove references to the serial device and just include the messages

Comment: what do you mean that "they're not presentable"?

Comment: When I say "not presentable" I mean that latitude of -51.234567 looks like '5123.4567', 'S'

Comment: I thought my code was just changing the way the numbers were printed, but it seems the accuracy is altered at some point. The NMEA messages are accurate, but the output of this code isn't. Am I making sense?

Comment: A NMEA latitude of `5123.4567` is *not* 51.234567 degrees.  It's 51 degrees, 23.4567 minutes, which works out to about 51.390945 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read RMC messages.
Their format is described [>>here<<](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/NMEA.html#_rmc_recommended_minimum_navigation_information)

Latitude format: **ddmm.ffff**

Longitude format: **dddmm.ffff**

**dd/ddd** - degrees

**mm** - minutes

**.** - decimal point

**ffff** - fractional minutes

This means that you need to extract the first two (latitude) or three (longitude) digits and treat them as degrees and treat the remaining part as minutes (two digits, dot, a few more digits).
I can't really help you with the code, I don't know python at all, but you should be aware that the number of digits representing fractional minutes may be different on different receivers.  Don't hardcode the number of digits to read (except 2/3 digits for degrees), but keep reading until you hit a comma.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just applying the cardinal directions wrong.  For example, [Grytviken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grytviken) has the coordinates: 54°16′53.4″S 36°30′28.8″W, if I pass:

```
data = ['$GNRMC', '...', '...', "5416.89", "S", "03630.48", "W", ...]
```

to your code I get `-53.7185 -35.4920` back, which isn't right because it's not applying the `S` and `W` to the minute fields.

I'd recommend writing and testing a small function to parse the "ddmm.mm" and "sign" fields together, something like:

```
SIGN_NSEW = { 'N': 1, 'S': -1, 'E': 1, 'W': -1 }

def rmc_ddmm_to_degrees(val, sign):
    dd, mm = divmod(float(val), 100)
    return (dd + mm / 60) * SIGN_NSEW[sign]

latitude  = rmc_ddmm_to_degrees(data[3], data[4])
longitude = rmc_ddmm_to_degrees(data[5], data[6])

print(f"{latitude:.4f} {longitude:.4f}")
```

which makes it easier to ensure it gets the correct value of `-54.2815 -36.5080`.